# Python 3.9: "async_generator can't be used in 'await' expression" when using yield in __anext__

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, python-asyncio

I'm trying the following:

```
class Payload_Session_Generator:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    async def __anext__(self):
        async for payload in generate_fb_payload():
            if type(payload) != str:
                yield payload
            else:
                StopAsyncIteration

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self
```

This is then passed as an instance to a different function and the `__aiter__` method is called explicitly and `_iter` is an object of the above class:

```
chunk = await self._iter.__anext__()
```

This then yields the following error:

> TypeError: object async_generator can't be used in 'await' expression

Comment: ``__anext__`` must ``return`` *one* element. ``__aiter__`` is what may ``yield`` *multiple* elements.

Answer (score 6):

Change your code like

```
class PayloadSessionGenerator:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    async def __aiter__(self):
        async for payload in generate_fb_payload():
            if type(payload) != str:
                yield payload
            else:
                StopAsyncIteration
```

try next call

```
x = Payload_Session_Generator()
chunk = await x.__anext__()
```

Answer (score 5):

An asynchronous generator is similar to a regular generator: `__anext__` must *provide one* element each time it is called. Since an (async) generator is an (async) iterator, it *must* return the object itself.

As such, `__anext__` should use `return` instead of `yield`:

```
class Payload_Session_Generator:
    async def __anext__(self):
        async for payload in generate_fb_payload():
            if type(payload) != str:
                return payload            # return one element
            else:
                raise StopAsyncIteration  # raise at end of iteration

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self
```

Note that if a class uses just `__anext__` and `__aiter__`, it is simpler to write a proper async generator. An async generator is defined using `async def` and `yield` in the body:

```
async def payload_session_generator():
    async for payload in generate_fb_payload():
        if type(payload) != str:
            yield payload  # yield each element
        else:
            break          # exiting ends iteration
```